# Can a Fragment be the central hub for other Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im refactoring an older app, that has a fragment that needs to be cut into smaller fragments. The main fragment is sort of a step by step, report a problem page. Its build with a view flipper reacting to the next button and gets data with Retrofit. Why they chose to make a fragment behave like an activity is strange to me.

**Example** 
Page 1 "What is the problem page topic" 
Page 2 "What is the problem with the selected topic" 
Page 3 "Comment on the problem" 
Page 4 "Send problem data entered on each page(fragments)"

My problem is that i'm at a loss about how to make fragment to fragment communication via a underlying fragment, since all i can find online is with a activity in between the fragments. (viewModels and interfaces).

Do i need to make a new activity to be the holder of fragments and communications or is there a way with the current fragment.

**Update**
I realized that the app uses navigation drawer to navigate the the fragment i wanted to replace with an activity and to my understanding, using navigation drawer and activity is bad practice. So my question goes again.

If i navigate to `Fragment_A` with navigation drawer, and in that Fragment i have each step split up into smaller fragments like `Fragment_A1`, `Fragment_A2` and so on. How can i communicate between them. How can `Fragment_A2` know what `int` i picked from a list in `Fragment_A1`.

instead of the navigation drawer navigation to `Fragment_A`, should it navigate to `Fragment_A1`?

I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: If fragmentA wants to communicate with fragmentB, it should use the underlying activity as a communication channel. I would suggest you make a `ViewModel`, attach it to the activity and retrieve it in the fragments.

Comment: was also where i was going, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways when it comes to communication between fragments. To name a few:

1. Using activity & interface(s) as mediator
2. Using target fragment concept (if you have Page 2 as fragment, then in order to communicate with Page 1 you could pass Page 1 fragment as target fragment via setTargetFragment
3. Using even bus (like otto for example)
4. Using local broadcasts and receivers
5. Using shared view model

...? :)

I'd suggest to go with p5 (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing)

Comment: Was also my thinking, seems like the best option